# How does using cursor in oracle sql solve this problem?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my code.

```
declare
    vdate tblstudent.retdate%type;
    vnum number := 1;
-- studentSeq tblstudent.studentSeq%type;
-- studentSeq number;
    CURSOR CUR --declare a cursor
IS
SELECT
STUDENTSEQ,
retdate
FROM
TBLSTUDENT;
-- where
-- status = 'Class completed' and
-- COMPLETIONSTATUS='Completed' and
-- vnum = STUDENTSEQ;
begin
    open cur;
-- FETCH EX_CUR INTO PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME; --Get data from cursor
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE(vdate);
        loop
        fetch cur into vnum, vdate;
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(vdate);
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(vnum);
        EXIT WHEN CUR %NOTFOUND;
        end loop;
    CLOSE cur; -- close cursor
END;
```

the result is

```
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 20/09/24
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 1
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 18/10/21
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 2
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 20/02/16
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 3
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 20/12/23
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 4
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 21/07/24
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 5
...
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 18/02/02
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 297
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 21/05/25
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 298
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 16/12/12
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 299
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 20/04/21
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 300
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 16/02/19
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 301
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 16/02/19
[2021-05-29 20:45:39] 301
```

In this state, I tried to write the following code to get the data corresponding to the where condition.

```
declare
    vdate tblstudent.retdate%type;
    vnum number := 1;
    studentSeq tblstudent.studentSeq%type;
-- studentSeq number;
    CURSOR CUR --declare a cursor
IS
SELECT
STUDENTSEQ,
retdate
FROM
TBLSTUDENT
    where
status = 'Class completed' and
      COMPLETIONSTATUS='Completed' and
              vnum = STUDENTSEQ;
```

However, the desired where condition does not work properly and only one row is output as a result.

I am wondering how to solve this problem.
best regard

Comment: @Abra yes `STUDENTSEQ` is primary key of `TBLSTUDENT`

Comment: The variable `vnum` has the value `1` at the time you open the cursor, so you get that row. I'm not sure what you are trying to do though.

Answer (score 0):

The vnum = STUDENTSEQ; condition at the end of the query seems to be causing the problem here.

First of all, a quick note. It is standard practice to write the column name on the left and the variable/constant to compare it with on the right. So STUDENTSEQ = vnum; would have been more understandable.

As pointed out by William in the comments above, as there is no change in the value of vnum, the result that is fetched by the select query is the record corresponding to STUDENTSEQ = 1.

If we wish to get records for all values of STUDENTSEQ, do we really need that condition here?